# Java - How to create tabs look like words or excel 2007

Tags: java

i have problem, i need make an application user interface looklike word or excel but different feature, in word or excel 2007 you can see tab on top of application. My problem is how to create these tabs look like this? what's component i need to use? ( Tabs are Home - Insert - Page layout and so on ... )

look line image below:

http://www.galcho.com/Blog/content/binary/Word2003Menus.jpg

and other question is how to store session if using java application? store session in file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pure Swing solution, have a look at the flamingo library:

https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/flamingo

This can also be integrated into the NetBeans platform:

http://www.pinkmatter.co.za/Blog/tabid/65/EntryId/2/Netbeans-platform-ribbon-bar-library.aspx

Comment: give me the userguide or tutorial for it please!

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean ribbon.  There are several implementations around.

As I prefer SWT over swing/awt I'd point you at [hexapixel's](http://hexapixel.com/projects/ribbon) SWT based implementation.  Have a look at the screen shots.

Comment: could you give me user guide for it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about normal menu bar, not ribbon, you can take a look at this [excellent tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) to create menu bar.